# Imagick missing but extension and module exists

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in pdfThumbnail.php on line 2`

when running

```
$im = new Imagick($_GET['pdf'].'[0]');
```

However if I run

```
$test = system('rpm - qa | grep ImageMagick'); 
echo $test;
```

I get the following:

```
ImageMagick-6.2.8.0-4.el5_5.3 
ImageMagick-devel-6.2.8.0-4.el5_5.3 
ImageMagick-devel-6.2.8.0-4.el5_5.3 
ImageMagick-6.2.8.0-4.el5_5.3 
ImageMagick-6.2.8.0-4.el5_5.3
```

Inside the `phpInfo` I can't find a section for the imagemagick module, however
inside php.ini (the one listed inside `phpInfo();`, I find:

`extension=imagick.so`

My extension path is set to
`extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules"` and inside that folder I get:

```
dbase.so    libMagickCore.so  mysqli.so      soap.so             xsl.so
dom.so      libMagick++.so    mysql.so       sw-engine
gd.so       libMagickWand.so  pdo_mysql.so   _unused_imagick.so
imagick.so  libpdf_php.so     pdo.so         xmlreader.so
imap.so     mbstring.so       pdo_sqlite.so  xmlwriter.so
```

However imagick is in white while the rest are in green.

What else could be causing my problem

Comment: Where did you find `imagick.so`?  I mean, the file itself, where did it come from before you put it in the extensions directory?  It doesn't sound like you actually [*installed* the PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick).

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right php.ini?

Comment: @Pekka yep, its the php.ini defined in `phpInfo();` .. @Charles - so I followed these steps exactly: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems getting ImageMagick to work on a OS X 10.6.8 / XAMPP setup.  The problem turned out to be that the various binaries involved were not playing nicely because MacPorts was not building Universal binaries.

This blog post was most helpful: http://mikepuchol.com/2010/08/26/getting-mamp-1-9-to-work-with-image-magick-imagick-so-and-other-flora/